# Right approach for presenting charts in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, c#-3.0

Tried few methods for presenting charts in asp.net mvc,but each has its own disadvantages, still not knowing the best approach for presenting the charts

the first approach is the below one

```
   public ActionResult Chart1()
  {
      Chart chart = new Chart();

      chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());

      chart.Series.Add(new Series("Data"));

      chart.Legends.Add(new Legend("Stores"));
      chart.Series["Data"].ChartType =           SeriesChartType.Pie;
      chart.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY(1.0, 5.0);
      chart.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY(2.0, 9.0);

      var returnStream = new MemoryStream();
      chart.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
      chart.SaveImage(returnStream);
      returnStream.Position = 0;
      return new FileStreamResult(returnStream,           "image/png");
  }

  view

  <img src="/MyHome/Chart1" alt="" />
```

By using the above method im able to present the chart, as the action method is returning the image directly, im not able to present any controls like textbox,button on the same page of the chart

Is there any other better approach than this?

Answer (score 0):

Iam using Razor.

First Make a view only for rendereing chart control like this.

Charts.cshtml :

```
 @{
        Layout = null;
        var mychart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
          .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
          .AddSeries(
              chartType: "Bubble",
              name: "Employee",
              xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
              yValues: new[] { "2", "7", "5", "3" });              

    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Charts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @mychart.Write();
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then Make a view where you want to place your chart control.

Main View :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>MainView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="Charts"/> //Here src value must be the URL of your chart view.
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="button" name="Button"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now your image returned from your chart view is rendered in `img` you specify in your `main` view.

You also make a partialview for this to obtained some optimization.

Comment: He should not point the image source to the URL of the Charts view, since it also renders HTML. Rather, he should render it via @Html.Partial("Charts").    
Even better, avoid having the View contain rendering logic for the chart, and instead make a strongly typed model that the controller fills, and only let the Chart.cshtml view render the view. This way, he could also make a DisplayTemplate for the Chart model and render it with @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Chart)

Comment: the problem in my code is, the view is not getting called as the action method "return new FileStreamResult(returnStream,      "image/png"); is returning image, so the view is not getting called..

Comment: @SMK: I have a query regarding the labels shown in chart. If we are using column chart, and if we have number of columns, then the chart only shows the every other column label. What should be done to show every columns label?

Answer (score 0):

Make a strongly typed model for the view where you want the chart to appear:

```
public class SomeViewWithAChartModel {
    // Other model data goes here

    public Chart Chart { get; set; } // <---- Add this
}
```

Have your controller action fill and return this to your view, whenever you want to display a chart:

```
public ActionResult SomeViewWithAChart()
  {
      var chart = new Chart()
      // Set chart specifics...

      var model = new SomeViewWithAChartModel { Chart = chart };

      return View(model);
  }
```

Make a partial view to render the chart along with any HTML elements you want to show along side it.

Chart.cshtml partial view:

```
@model Chart

<div>
    @Model.Write();
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Tada! />
</div>
```

Render the partial chart-view in views where you want your chart to appear, along with the "Tada!" button, for instance our SomeViewWithAChart view:

SomeViewWithAChart.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Some View with a chart and a button</title>
</head>
<body>
     @Html.Partial("Chart", Model.Chart)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my controller action is returning image,"return new FileStreamResult(returnStream, "image/png");", how can i add return  view in my action method?

Comment: By changing your controller action to return the model class containing the Chart. Just replace "return new FileStreamResult(...);" with "return View(Model);"